Marketing Cloud Engagement
Requirement: If someone visits our website, whether they are known or unknown, we capture their data. Additionally, we track details such as the specific tabs they navigate to, live interactions on the site, and any buttons they click. We also collect data based on their geographic region.
Based on my requirements, I am unsure how to determine which solution is better: Marketing Cloud Web Studio or Personalization(Interaction Studio) Studio.

While Personalization is more capable, you don't put forward any requirements which go beyond what Web and Mobile Analytics in Marketing Cloud can provide. Remember, Personalization is a paid addition to SFMC, while WMA is provided as part of the standard platform. It can be used, through implementation of Web Collect Code to gather information about pages visited on your website. When you are able to identify the visitor, you can call the setUserInfo call, passing a suitable identifier, allowing you to match the anonymous behaviour with your 1st party data. As this data is being stored in Data Extensions in SFMC, you will be able to use it for segmentation as needed.
Please read more details in this article, with will iterate capabilities and showcase how you can build such an implementation yourself. Given the hight price of Personalisation, the lack of clear requirements for personalising web experience, and the significantly more complex implementation work of Personalization over Web and Mobile Analytics, I will give WMA a chance and perhaps build an MVP based on this.
Also as you wrote on Trailblazer Groups, your team has no experience with Personalization - adding this to equation provides even more weight to going with WMA as a pilot/MVP.
Let me know should you have any questions.
